Logical Test in Image instance
I'm working on a Power Apps application where I want to display different images based on the value of a field called 'Tipo de Ocorrência'. I am using the following formula in the Image property of an Image control:
If(ThisItem. 'Tipo de Ocorrência'.Value = "Roubo",
   "crime.png",
   If(ThisItem. 'Tipo de Ocorrência'.Value = "Acidente",
      "crash.jpg",
      "DefaultImage.png"
    )
)

Snapshot of App Screen:

However, the images are not displaying as expected. Here are the steps I've taken:

Verified that the image files "crime.png", "crash.jpg", and "DefaultImage.png" are correctly uploaded in the Power Apps media library.

Tested each image by setting the Image property directly to "crime.png", "crash.jpg", and "DefaultImage.png", and the images display correctly.

Added a Label control to display ThisItem.'Tipo de Ocorrência'.Value to ensure that the field contains the correct values ("Roubo" or "Acidente").


Despite these checks, the conditional logic does not seem to work, and the images do not appear based on the value of 'Tipo de Ocorrência'.
What could be the issue, and how can I fix it to ensure the correct image displays based on the condition?

Have a look at: If and Switch functions. In your case Switch would be ideal. Note how If can have multiple conditions (no need to nest).

To set an image you specify the media name as a property without the extension.
Try:
Switch(
  ThisItem.'Tipo de Ocorrência'.Value,
  "Roubo", 'crime',
  "Acidente", 'crash',  
  'DefaultImage'
)

